# Access 2007: "with block" error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm not an expert in Access and/or programming; so, it's pretty sure that my question would be sort of dumb.. yet, I need your help, so.. I dared to come and ask :)

So, here it is the thing: I've a form which, when closed, will insert and update some records at a previously created table via VBA code. The thing is that I've created the code as close as I know for doing sucha task, but I keep recieving the error message '91' from the VBA compiler: "Object variable or with block variable not set".

Could anyone help me with this issue? Thanks a lot in advanced; the full code I'm using is as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
Dim dbs As Database
Dim rst As recordSet
Dim auxGastoId, auxFecha
Dim auxReg

DoCmd.Echo False
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.OpenQuery "SueldosNuevoRegistroConsulta"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.Echo True

auxGastoId = DMax("id_gasto", "Gastos")
auxFecha = DLookup("fecha_gasto", "Gastos", "id_gasto = " & auxGastoId)

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Empleados", dbOpenDynaset)

rst.MoveFirst

Do While rst.EOF = False

If (Me.nombre_completo <> Null) Then
  If (Me.sueldo <> 0) Then
    dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO SueldosTempo (fecha_gasto) VALUES (" & _
       auxFecha & ");"

    auxReg = DMax("id_gasto_detalle", "SueldosTempo")

   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET id_gasto = " & _ 
       auxGastoId & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET cantidad = " & "1" & _
       " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET servicio = ""Sueldo (" & _
       Me.nombre_completo & ")"" WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET monto_servicio = " & _ 
       Me.sueldo & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET fecha_gasto = " & _
       auxFecha & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"

 ElseIf (Me.bono <> 0) Then
   dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO SueldosTempo (fecha_gasto) VALUES (" & _
       auxFecha & ");"

   auxReg = DMax("id_gasto_detalle", "SueldosTempo")

   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET id_gasto = " & _
       auxGastoId & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET cantidad = " & "1" & _
       " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET servicio = ""Bono (" & _
       Me.nombre_completo & ")""  WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET monto_servicio = " & _
       Me.bono & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
   dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET fecha_gasto = " & _
       auxFecha & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"

   ElseIf (Me.hrExtra <> 0) Then
     dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO SueldosTempo (fecha_gasto) VALUES (" & _
       auxFecha & ");"

     auxReg = DMax("id_gasto_detalle", "SueldosTempo")

     dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET id_gasto = " & _
       auxGastoId & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
     dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET cantidad = " & "1" & _
       " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
     dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET servicio = ""HrExtra (" & _
       Me.nombre_completo & ")""  WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
     dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET monto_servicio = " & _
       Me.hrExtra & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
     dbs.Execute "UPDATE SueldosTempo SET fecha_gasto = " & _
       auxFecha & " WHERE id_gasto_detalle = " & auxReg & ";"
  Else
  End If
  Else
  End If

  rst.MoveNext

  Loop

  dbs.Close

  Set rst = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

  End Sub
```

Comment: What line is generating the error? Where is `dbs` assigned? (You show an assignment to `db` and `rst`, but not `dbs`, yet you repeatedly use `dbs.Execute`.

Comment: Hello Ken: thanks a lot for the such *quick* responce :). The line of coe that gives the error is close to the end: "dbs.Close"

Comment: mm.. I see.. so I'm having such a DUMB thing as a variable name inconsistency? O.O .. you are quite a great observer.. I'll look into it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: **Always** include Option Explicit at the top of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll solve your problem by changing this line:
`Set db = CurrentDb()` to `set dbs = CurrentDb()`

And adding `Option Explicit` as your first line in the module.

`dbs.close` is causing an error because you never assign `dbs` a value.

If you had enabled option explicit while writing this, the IDE would have thrown a compile error letting you know that db was never defined.

Edit:

Also change `db = nothing` to `dbs = nothing`.

Comment: Greetings: just to let you know that your detailed responce hit in the spot. This might seem simple practices yet, not necessarily all the programers are aware of them.. my deepest regards: all solved perfectly :)